# keepassx + clipman: passwords don't get deleted after x seconds

Tags: keepassx

In KeepassX (v0.4.3 on xubuntu 15.10) preferences you can specify whether the copied passwords should get deleted after a few seconds. However this doesn't work since I use clipman clipboard manager. Does anyone have a solution for this?